# search logs with only upper-case letters on stackdriver

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I need to filter logs on stackdriver.
Can I write filter with upper-case letters?

For example, when I have logs like

> ERROR xxx
>   error xxx

and I'd like to pick up just

> ERROR xxx

So how can I write filter on this case?

Comment: Hey @Y Natsume!
If the answer worked for you, could you accept it to give it more visibility over the community and help other user with the same question to find it more easily? =)

Answer (score 2):

Looking for logs based on letter case for the string you are looking for is not possible using Stackdriver Logging since string comparison is not case sensitive, as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries?hl=en_US&_ga=2.172266403.-1030369614.1561980221#getting-started). If you want to make some distinction between those 2 logs, you will need to specify it in another way. Reading the provided documentation might give you other alternative solutions for what you wish to achieve.